# How to hide div using jquery or java script if value is 0.00?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hide

Hello i would like to hide a span and a div if the value is 0.00..here is my code

```
<span class="price-old"><%=getCurrentAttribute('item','custitem_sumisho_listprice')%    </span>
<span class="price-new"><%=getCurrentAttribute('item','custitem_sumisho_onlineprice')%> </span>
<div class="save-sale" style="font-size: .8em; padding-top: 4em"><%=getCurrentAttribute('item','custitem_sumisho_totalsave')%>
```

In the above code if the div of class="save-sale" will have 0.00 value then i would like to hide the class="price-old" and class="save-sale".Here getattribute tag will get the value of item price.

I have tried the below jquery but its not working

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/site/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function () {
if ($(".save-sale").text() == "0.00") {

 $(".save-sale").hide();
}
});
</script>
```

Comment: What is the actual content of that div? There might be some whitespace or other characters preventing it from passing the check.

Comment: @EmreAcar Yes they are, it's in a jQuery document ready handler.

Comment: Maybe just try trimming text: `if ($.trim($(".save-sale").text()) == "0.00")`. And you'd have better to post rendered html code instead of this useless server side code. BTW, `.text()` will return only first matched element text value, so if more than one element with same class, your logic will fail here

Comment: Try adding a `</div>`.

Comment: Use firebug to debug your code, so you will know what values you are getting for your fields

Comment: [If you add in the `</div>` your code works](http://jsfiddle.net/ne58zqr2/2/)

Comment: Works fine for me. http://jsfiddle.net/kz2j2jjy/5/

Comment: You're also missing a `>` before the first `</span>`

Comment: <%=getCurrentAttribute('item','custitem_sumisho_totalsave')%> will fetch the stored price value of items at runtime its netsuite tag

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to hide the class="price-old" and class="save-sale", you'll need to include both in your function. As written in your question, you only included .save-sale

```
$(function () {
  if ($(".save-sale").text() == "0.00") {

    $(".save-sale").hide();
    $(".price-old").hide();
  }
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0ymaL8qL/)

Answer (score 0):

Add this script either under your above code in script tags, in a document on read function or in an on load function.

```
var old = document.getElementsByClassName("price-old")[0];
var div = document.getElementsByClassName("save-sale")[0];
if (div.innerHTML.trim() == "0.00") { //.trim() will remove extra whitespace
  div.remove();
  old.remove();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What all the other answers ignore is that the numeric value of `0` might not render as `"0.00"` in your input. If you're checking numeric values then you should first convert it to a numeric value. Also beware of rounding errors and edge cases when working with floating point values and never try do an exact comparison. A safe approach here would be:

```
var saveValue = Math.abs(parseFloat($(".save-sale").text()));
if (saveValue<=0.001) { ... }
```

However, is it really necessary to do this check in Javascript, client-side? Is that value of `.save-sale` going to change client-side? If not, rather do your logic in Razor and show/hide the other element based on server-side logic.

Answer (score 0):

First, fix your HTML errors. You're missing a close `>` before the first `</span>` so the `getCurrentAttribute` method will fail:

```
<span class="price-old">
  <%=getCurrentAttribute('item','custitem_sumisho_listprice')%
</span>
```

And you're missing a `</div>` here.

```
<div class="save-sale" style="font-size: .8em; padding-top: 4em">
  <%=getCurrentAttribute('item','custitem_sumisho_totalsave')%>
```

Then update your JavaScript by adding in that extra `hide` for `.price-old`:

```
$(function () {
  if ($(".save-sale").text() == "0.00") {
    $(".save-sale").hide();
    $(".price-old").hide();
  }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Depends on how you are getting the value using a number instead of a string

as you can see here it works fine just closing the `div` which is missing from your HTML source

http://jsfiddle.net/osk6ed2m/1/